# Mailto body, special characters?

Tags: mobile, mailto

I'm trying to have a mailto: body with multiple paragraphs and a URL. I should probably note this is for a mobile web application.

1. Is there a reason why I can't use \n (even inside JavaScript strings) for new lines? Instead, I'm using %0D%0A.
2. I'd like to enclose my URL in <>'s so email clients can properly identify it as a URL, but when I try to do that the entire URL doesn't show up at all in the body. Is it being escaped, or something? How do I fix this/use <>'s to wrap it?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't know about the first question, but you probably need to use HTML entities `&lt;` for < and `&gt;` for > in order to get them into your HTML document correctly.

Comment: Hmm..still doesn't work. It just makes the entire URL (plus the <>'s) disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tryed encoding the values with javascript?

eg

```
<a href="demo@email.com?subject='+encodeURI('emailSubject')+'&body='+encodeURI('emailBody')+'">
```